# Rotate between videos

Tags: php, html, video

So I had an initial code that rotated between 30 images that worked perfectly. I'm trying to adapt the code to rotate between 30 videos now but haven't been able to make it work in that the videos are not loading in my main page. Am I missing something that I have to change? Code below. Thanks

Main page

```
$key = rand(1,30); 
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <source src="rotate.php?num=<?php echo $key; ?>
```

rotate.php

```
    <?php
    $folder = './videos';
    $extList = array();
    $extList['mp4'] = 'video/mp4';

$img = null;

if (substr($folder,-1) != '/') {
    $folder = $folder.'/';
}
$imageNumber = 3;

if(isset($_GET['num'])){
    $imageNumber = $_GET['num'];
}
if (isset($_GET['img'])) {
    $imageInfo = pathinfo($_GET['img']);
    if (
        isset( $extList[ strtolower( $imageInfo['extension'] ) ] ) &&
        file_exists( $folder.$imageInfo['basename'] )
    ) {
        $img = $folder.$imageInfo['basename'];
    }
} else {
    $fileList = array();
    $handle = opendir($folder);
    while ( false !== ( $file = readdir($handle) ) ) {
        $file_info = pathinfo($file);
        if (
            isset( $extList[ strtolower( $file_info['extension'] ) ] )
        ) {
            $fileList[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);

    if (count($fileList) > 0) {

        $img = $folder.$fileList[$imageNumber];
    }
}

if ($img!=null) {
    $imageInfo = pathinfo($img);
    $contentType = 'Content-type: '.$extList[ $imageInfo['extension'] ];
    header ($contentType);
    readfile($img);
} else {
    if ( function_exists('imagecreate') ) {
        header ("Content-type: video/mp4");
        $im = @imagecreate (100, 100)
            or die ("Cannot initialize new GD image stream");
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0,0,0);
        imagestring ($im, 2, 5, 5,  "IMAGE ERROR", $text_color);
        imagepng ($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean with _"make it work"_.

Comment: I mean it does not load the videos. It works if I directly put the actual video source, but this rotation of videos is not working

Comment: Added more description to the issue